# typescript index signature accessors

Tags: javascript, typescript, accessor, index-signature

I would like my javascript data to be like this:

```
"dogs": {
    "ada": {
        age: 7,
        breed: poodle
    },
    "levin": {
        age: 5,
        breed: shitzu
    },
    ...
}
```

Where the name is an object key.  I have this typescript class:

```
export class Dog {
  [dogName: string]: DogDetails;
}
```

The only way I could see that I could encapsulate methods to create accesssors is by adding these static methods to `Dog`:

```
  public static getDogName(dog: Dog): string {
    return Object.keys(dog).toString();
  }

  public static getDogDetails(dog: Dog): DogDetails {
    return dog[Dog.getDogName(dog)];
  }
```

Which is pretty horrible.  One reason being is that static access is required:

```
Dog.getDogName(dog)  // this is how it must be done
```

And seems so contrary to how this should be written, which would be:

```
dog.getName();  // this unfortunately can't be done
```

The situation would be much nicer if there was a way to get access to the index signature value.  However I could not find any way to achieve this.  Is there a way or is there a better way to write this class?

Note that this is not possible with classes using index signatures:

```
public getName(): string {   // this won't work
    Object.keys(this).toString();
}
```

Since it complains `Property 'getName' of type '() => string' is not assignable to string index type 'DogDetails'`

---

Update after answer from **@amiramw** and comments conversation:

The angular component where this is being used is:

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let dog of dogs">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-avatar item-start>
        <img src="assets/img/dog.jpg"/>
      </ion-avatar>
      <h4>{{Dog.getName(dog)}}</h4>
      <p>{{Dog.getDogDetails(dog).breed}}</p>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

After the feedback it seems I'll need to write:

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let dogName of getDogNames()">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-avatar item-start>
        <img src="assets/img/dog.jpg"/>
      </ion-avatar>
      <h4>{{dogName}}</h4>
      <p>{{getDogDetails(dogName).breed}}</p>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

Where `getDogNames()` is:

```
  public getDogNames(): string[] {
    if (this.dogs) {
      return Object.keys(this.dogs);
    } else {
      return new Array<string>();
    }
  }
```

And `getDogDetails()` is:

```
  public getDogDetails(name: string): DogDetails {
    return this.dogs[name];
  }
```

Which works but isn't what I was looking for.  I will give @amiramw credit for the suggestion as to a solution to my overall problem.

However I'd much appreciate knowing if there is a way to obtain the typescript index signature value??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an interface for each dog's data and define a map from string to that interface. The interface can be named (for reuse) or anonymous:

```
enum Breed {
    poodle,
    shitzu
}
let dogs : { [key:string]: {age: number, breed: Breed} } = {
    "ada": {
        age: 7,
        breed: Breed.poodle
    },
    "levin": {
        age: 5,
        breed: Breed.shitzu
    }
};
```

Comment: How do you get the name?  eg. "ada"

Comment: You can get the dogs' list by calling `Object.keys(dogs)` and then you have the names and you can access each dog data by `doing dogs[dogName]`. Other option is to maintain the dogs list in an array and add `name` property to the interface.

Comment: Ok I see your approach.  I don't think your typescript code is essentially any different to what I have, it is just your approach of accessing the data.  This may be how I have to do it, however it is contrary to how I think it should be done and different to text-book cases.  I will update my question to qualify with the angular code being used to traverse this data.  Thanks for your efforts.